# Is there a way to test the name of downloaded file in protractor?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

Is there a way to test the name and/or the extension of a downloaded file by my application in protractor?

Comment: I don't see how that's a duplicate. The other questions asks how to test whether the file downloaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Using node.js filesystem, you can read the files in a directory and verify something about them in a protractor test. There is nothing special provided by protractor to emulate that functionality.